# using typeof to check if a variable is not undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

why is typeof not checking if a variable is undefined  with the below snippets:

```
 if(typeof res.data.data[1].name !== undefined){
//the idea is that if code gets here it means it contains some data
    .......
    }
```

with the above check I still get this outcome at the if block

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be because of res.data.data is null , just add a null check

```
if(res.data.data && typeof res.data.data[1].name !== undefined){
```

Comment: I did this and it worked well 
if(res.data.data[1] && typeof res.data.data[1].name !== undefined){

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because `res.data.data[1]` is undefined itself. I'd suggest expand your condition to something like:

```
const { data = [] } = res.data;
if (data[1] && typeof data[1].name !== 'undefined') {
  // Do somehing
}
```

Also your check is incorrect as you are comparing typeof result with `undefined` while it returns a string, in this case `'undefined'`